# Pandas Building a subtable based on means

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a DataFrame containing columns of numerical and non-numerical data. Here's a slice of it:

```
ATG12 Norm     ATG5 Norm    ATG7 Norm    Cancer Stage    
5.55           4.99         8.99         IIA
4.87           5.77         8.88         IIA
5.98           7.88         8.34         IIC
```

I want to group data by Cancer Stage, take the mean of every numerical data column and produce a table which lists means for each Cancer Stage; like this:

```
Cancer Stage    ATG12 Mean    ATG5 Mean    ATG7 Mean
IIA             5.03          6.20         8.34
IIB             7.45          4.22         7.99
IIIA            5.32          3.85         6.68
```

I've figured out the groupby and mean() functions and can compute the means for one column at a time with:

```
AVG = data.groupby("Cancer Stage")['ATG12 Norm'].mean()
```

But that only gives me:

```
Cancer Stage    
IIA             5.03      
IIB             7.45
IIIA            5.32
Name: ATG12 Norm, dtype: float64
```

How can I apply this process to all the columns I want at once and produce a dataframe of it all? Sorry if this is a repeat; the pandas questions I've found that seem to be about related topics are all over my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
df.groupby('Cancer Stage').mean()
```

or

```
df.groupby('Cancer Stage')['ATG12 Norm','ATG5 Norm'].mean()
```

Example data with extra text column:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

data='''ATG12 Norm     ATG5 Norm    ATG7 Norm    Cancer Stage    Text
5.55           4.99         8.99         IIA    ABC
4.87           5.77         8.88         IIA    ABC
5.98           7.88         8.34         IIC    ABC'''

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=None, sep='\s{2,}')

print df
print df.groupby('Cancer Stage')['ATG12 Norm','ATG5 Norm'].mean()
print df.groupby('Cancer Stage').mean()
```

result:

```
   ATG12 Norm  ATG5 Norm  ATG7 Norm Cancer Stage Text
0        5.55       4.99       8.99          IIA  ABC
1        4.87       5.77       8.88          IIA  ABC
2        5.98       7.88       8.34          IIC  ABC


              ATG12 Norm  ATG5 Norm
Cancer Stage                       
IIA                 5.21       5.38
IIC                 5.98       7.88


              ATG12 Norm  ATG5 Norm  ATG7 Norm
Cancer Stage                                  
IIA                 5.21       5.38      8.935
IIC                 5.98       7.88      8.340
```

Comment: Both of your suggestions were helpful. 
df.groupby('Cancer Stage').mean() gave me means for every value in the table
df.groupby('Cancer Stage')['ATG12 Norm','ATG5 Norm'].mean() allowed me to choose which values we averaged. Thank you